# How to save an image locally using Python whose URL address I already know?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I know the URL of an image on Internet.

e.g. http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg, which contains the logo of Google.

Now, how can I download this image using Python without actually opening the URL in a browser and saving the file manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)

Answer (score 407, accepted):

## Python 2

Here is a more straightforward way if all you want to do is save it as a file:

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg", "local-filename.jpg")
```

The second argument is the local path where the file should be saved.

## Python 3

As SergO suggested the  code below should work with Python 3.

```
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg", "local-filename.jpg")
```

Comment: A good way to get filename from link is `filename = link.split('/')[-1]`

Comment: with urlretrieve I just get a 1KB file with a dict and 404 error text inside.Why? If I enter url into my browser I can get the picture

Comment: @Yebach: The site you are downloading from may be using cookies, the User-Agent or other headers to determine what content to serve you. These will be different between your browser and Python.

Comment: **[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urlretrieve#urllib.request.urlretrieve):** `import urllib.request` and `urllib.request.urlretrieve()`, accordingly.

Comment: How can I know if the the download has succeeded?

Comment: @SergO - can you add the Python 3 part to the original answer?

Comment: @sreejith-menon: my edition was rejected, so I published it as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39594029/685410)

Comment: @heltonbiker That won't work if the url has query parameters. Better to get the unadorned url first using [**`urlparse`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse)

Comment: This might not work at your end as the URL mentioned in the answer is no more having an image. Try with any other image URL and it works.

Comment: To get the original filename from the URL, use `import os; os.path.basename(your_url)`

Answer (score 29):

```
import urllib
resource = urllib.urlopen("http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg")
output = open("file01.jpg","wb")
output.write(resource.read())
output.close()
```

`file01.jpg` will contain your image.

Comment: You should open the file in binary mode: `open("file01.jpg", "wb")` Otherwise you may corrupt the image.

Comment: `urllib.urlretrieve` can save the image directly.

Comment: This was Python 2. Perhaps you have a newer version of Python?

Answer (score 21):

I wrote [a script that does just this](https://github.com/nateberman/Python-WebImageScraper), and it is available on my github for your use.

I utilized BeautifulSoup to allow me to parse any website for images. If you will be doing much web scraping (or intend to use my tool) I suggest you `sudo pip install BeautifulSoup`. Information on BeautifulSoup is available [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

For convenience here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import urllib

# use this image scraper from the location that 
#you want to save scraped images to

def make_soup(url):
    html = urlopen(url).read()
    return BeautifulSoup(html)

def get_images(url):
    soup = make_soup(url)
    #this makes a list of bs4 element tags
    images = [img for img in soup.findAll('img')]
    print (str(len(images)) + "images found.")
    print 'Downloading images to current working directory.'
    #compile our unicode list of image links
    image_links = [each.get('src') for each in images]
    for each in image_links:
        filename=each.split('/')[-1]
        urllib.urlretrieve(each, filename)
    return image_links

#a standard call looks like this
#get_images('http://www.wookmark.com')
```

Answer (score 19):

This can be done with requests. Load the page and dump the binary content to a file.

```
import os
import requests

url = 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1701/potw1636aN159_HST_2048.jpg'
page = requests.get(url)

f_ext = os.path.splitext(url)[-1]
f_name = 'img{}'.format(f_ext)
with open(f_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(page.content)
```

Comment: user headers in requests if getting bad request :)

Comment: Also, you likely want to check that `page.status_code == 200` before writing the file.

Answer (score 13):

**Python 3**

[urllib.request — Extensible library for opening URLs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urlretrieve#urllib.request.urlretrieve)

```
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

try:
    urlretrieve(image_url, image_local_path)
except FileNotFoundError as err:
    print(err)   # something wrong with local path
except HTTPError as err:
    print(err)  # something wrong with url
```

Answer (score 7):

I made a script expanding on Yup.'s script. I fixed some things. It will now bypass 403:Forbidden problems. It wont crash when an image fails to be retrieved. It tries to avoid corrupted previews. It gets the right absolute urls. It gives out more information. It can be run with an argument from the command line.

```
# getem.py
# python2 script to download all images in a given url
# use: python getem.py http://url.where.images.are

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import shutil
import requests
from urlparse import urljoin
import sys
import time

def make_soup(url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 
    html = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    return BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

def get_images(url):
    soup = make_soup(url)
    images = [img for img in soup.findAll('img')]
    print (str(len(images)) + " images found.")
    print 'Downloading images to current working directory.'
    image_links = [each.get('src') for each in images]
    for each in image_links:
        try:
            filename = each.strip().split('/')[-1].strip()
            src = urljoin(url, each)
            print 'Getting: ' + filename
            response = requests.get(src, stream=True)
            # delay to avoid corrupted previews
            time.sleep(1)
            with open(filename, 'wb') as out_file:
                shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
        except:
            print '  An error occured. Continuing.'
    print 'Done.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = sys.argv[1]
    get_images(url)
```

Answer (score 6):

A solution which works with Python 2 and Python 3:

```
try:
    from urllib.request import urlretrieve  # Python 3
except ImportError:
    from urllib import urlretrieve  # Python 2

url = "http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg"
urlretrieve(url, "local-filename.jpg")
```

or, if the additional requirement of [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) is acceptable and if it is a http(s) URL:

```
def load_requests(source_url, sink_path):
    """
    Load a file from an URL (e.g. http).

    Parameters
    ----------
    source_url : str
        Where to load the file from.
    sink_path : str
        Where the loaded file is stored.
    """
    import requests
    r = requests.get(source_url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(sink_path, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r:
                f.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 6):

Using requests library

```
import requests
import shutil,os

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'
}
currentDir = os.getcwd()
path = os.path.join(currentDir,'Images')#saving images to Images folder

def ImageDl(url):
    attempts = 0
    while attempts < 5:#retry 5 times
        try:
            filename = url.split('/')[-1]
            r = requests.get(url,headers=headers,stream=True,timeout=5)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                with open(os.path.join(path,filename),'wb') as f:
                    r.raw.decode_content = True
                    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw,f)
            print(filename)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            attempts+=1
            print(e)


ImageDl(url)
```

Comment: It seems the header is really important in my case, I was getting 403 errors. It worked.

Answer (score 5):

Use a simple python `wget` module to download the link. Usage below:

```
import wget
wget.download('http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is very short answer.

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://photogallery.sandesh.com/Picture.aspx?AlubumId=422040", "Abc.jpg")
```

Answer (score 2):

### Version for Python 3

I adjusted the code of @madprops for Python 3

```
# getem.py
# python2 script to download all images in a given url
# use: python getem.py http://url.where.images.are

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import shutil
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import sys
import time

def make_soup(url):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    return BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

def get_images(url):
    soup = make_soup(url)
    images = [img for img in soup.findAll('img')]
    print (str(len(images)) + " images found.")
    print('Downloading images to current working directory.')
    image_links = [each.get('src') for each in images]
    for each in image_links:
        try:
            filename = each.strip().split('/')[-1].strip()
            src = urljoin(url, each)
            print('Getting: ' + filename)
            response = requests.get(src, stream=True)
            # delay to avoid corrupted previews
            time.sleep(1)
            with open(filename, 'wb') as out_file:
                shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
        except:
            print('  An error occured. Continuing.')
    print('Done.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_images('http://www.wookmark.com')
```

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but for `python>=3.6` you can use [dload](https://pypi.org/project/dload/), i.e.:

```
import dload
dload.save("http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg")
```

if you need the image as `bytes`, use:

```
img_bytes = dload.bytes("http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg")
```

---

install using `pip3 install dload`

Answer (score 2):

Something fresh for Python 3 using Requests:

Comments in the code. Ready to use function.

```
import requests
from os import path

def get_image(image_url):
    """
    Get image based on url.
    :return: Image name if everything OK, False otherwise
    """
    image_name = path.split(image_url)[1]
    try:
        image = requests.get(image_url)
    except OSError:  # Little too wide, but work OK, no additional imports needed. Catch all conection problems
        return False
    if image.status_code == 200:  # we could have retrieved error page
        base_dir = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "images") # Use your own path or "" to use current working directory. Folder must exist.
        with open(path.join(base_dir, image_name), "wb") as f:
            f.write(image.content)
        return image_name

get_image("https://apod.nasddfda.gov/apod/image/2003/S106_Mishra_1947.jpg")
```

Answer (score 2):

this is the easiest method to download images.

```
import requests
from slugify import slugify

img_url = 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1701/potw1636aN159_HST_2048.jpg'
img = requests.get(img_url).content
img_file = open(slugify(img_url) + '.' + str(img_url).split('.')[-1], 'wb')
img_file.write(img)
img_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already have the url for the image, you could scrape it with [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho):

```py
from gazpacho import Soup
base_url = "http://books.toscrape.com"

soup = Soup.get(base_url)
links = [img.attrs["src"] for img in soup.find("img")]
```

And then download the asset with `urllib` as mentioned:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.request import urlretrieve as download

directory = "images"
Path(directory).mkdir(exist_ok=True)

link = links[0]
name = link.split("/")[-1]

download(f"{base_url}/{link}", f"{directory}/{name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# import the required libraries from Python
import pathlib,urllib.request 

# Using pathlib, specify where the image is to be saved
downloads_path = str(pathlib.Path.home() / "Downloads")

# Form a full image path by joining the path to the 
# images' new name

picture_path  = os.path.join(downloads_path, "new-image.png")

# "/home/User/Downloads/new-image.png"

# Using "urlretrieve()" from urllib.request save the image 
urllib.request.urlretrieve("//example.com/image.png", picture_path)

# urlretrieve() takes in 2 arguments
# 1. The URL of the image to be downloaded
# 2. The image new name after download. By default, the image is saved
#    inside your current working directory
```

Answer (score -1):

Download Image file, with avoiding all possible error:

```
import requests
import validators
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError


def is_downloadable(url):
  valid=validators. url(url)
  if valid==False:
    return False
  req = Request(url)
  try:
    response = urlopen(req)
  except HTTPError as e:
    return False
  except URLError as e:
    return False
  else:
    return True



for i in range(len(File_data)):   #File data Contain list of address for image 
                                                      #file
  url = File_data[i][1]
  try:
    if (is_downloadable(url)):
      try:
        r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
        if url.find('/'):
          fname = url.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
          fname = pth+File_data[i][0]+"$"+fname #Destination to save 
                                                   #image file
          open(fname, 'wb').write(r.content)
      except Exception as e:
        print(e)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Fun fact: the status can change between calling the `downloadable` function and actually downloading the file, making this exercise somewhat pointless

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so, this is my rudimentary attempt, and probably total overkill.
Update if needed, as this doesn't handle any timeouts, but, I got this working for fun.

Code listed here: https://github.com/JayRizzo/JayRizzoTools/blob/master/pyImageDownloader.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# =============================================================================
# Created Syst: MAC OSX High Sierra 21.5.0 (17G65)
# Created Plat: Python 3.9.5 ('v3.9.5:0a7dcbdb13', 'May  3 2021 13:17:02')
# Created By  : Jeromie Kirchoff
# Created Date: Thu Jun 15 23:31:01 2022 CDT
# Last ModDate: Thu Jun 16 01:41:01 2022 CDT
# =============================================================================
# NOTE: Doesn't work on SVG images at this time.
# I will look into this further: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6599172/1896134
# =============================================================================
import requests                                 # to get image from the web
import shutil                                   # to save it locally
import os                                       # needed
from os.path import exists as filepathexist     # check if file paths exist
from os.path import join                        # joins path for different os
from os.path import expanduser                  # expands current home
from pyuser_agent import UA                     # generates random UserAgent

class ImageDownloader(object):
    """URL ImageDownloader.
    Input : Full Image URL
    Output: Image saved to your ~/Pictures/JayRizzoDL folder.
    """
    def __init__(self, URL: str):
        self.url = URL
        self.headers = {"User-Agent" : UA().random}
        self.currentHome = expanduser('~')
        self.desktop = join(self.currentHome + "/Desktop/")
        self.download = join(self.currentHome + "/Downloads/")
        self.pictures = join(self.currentHome + "/Pictures/JayRizzoDL/")
        self.outfile = ""
        self.filename = ""
        self.response = ""
        self.rawstream = ""
        self.createdfilepath = ""
        self.imgFileName = ""
        # Check if the JayRizzoDL exists in the pictures folder.
        # if it doesn't exist create it.
        if not filepathexist(self.pictures):
            os.mkdir(self.pictures)
        self.main()

    def getFileNameFromURL(self, URL: str):
        """Parse the URL for the name after the last forward slash."""
        NewFileName = self.url.strip().split('/')[-1].strip()
        return NewFileName

    def getResponse(self, URL: str):
        """Try streaming the URL for the raw data."""
        self.response = requests.get(self.url, headers=self.headers, stream=True)
        return self.response

    def gocreateFile(self, name: str, response):
        """Try creating the file with the raw data in a custom folder."""
        self.outfile = join(self.pictures, name)
        with open(self.outfile, 'wb') as outFilePath:
            shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, outFilePath)
        return self.outfile

    def main(self):
        """Combine Everything and use in for loops."""
        self.filename = self.getFileNameFromURL(self.url)
        self.rawstream = self.getResponse(self.url)
        self.createdfilepath = self.gocreateFile(self.filename, self.rawstream)
        print(f"File was created: {self.createdfilepath}")
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Example when calling the file directly.
    ImageDownloader("https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png")
```