# python 3 import urllib.request module

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning to grab pictures from URL and found a Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286352/how-to-save-an-image-locally-using-python-whose-url-address-i-already-know). Since it's Python 3, I changed `import urllib` to `import urllib.request` and

`urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg", "local-filename.jpg")`

to

`urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg", "local-filename.jpg")`.

It doesn't work! It says `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlretrieve'`

I then changed `urllib.urlretrieve` to `def request.urlretrieve` and got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I also tried `def urlretrieve` and it's not working either.

Could anyone tell me how to get it right? Thanks!

What if the URL contains more than one pic?

Comment: In Python 3, `urllib.request.urlretrieve` should work. Can you post some of your code?

Comment: @hlt, it does not. you need `from urllib import request`

Comment: `import urllib.request` and then `urllib.request.urlretrieve` works perfectly fine on my 3.4.1

Comment: @hlt, I missed the second part of the scrambled text, I thought the OP only had an `import urllib` but I imagine the `urllib.request.urlretrieve` was not combined with the correct `import statement`

Comment: @hlt I tried it again and it's now working! Thanks! It's so strange that it did not work this morning...

Comment: @rain, you did not write it correctly this morning, python does not have off days ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use:

```
from urllib import request
request.urlretrieve("http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg", "local-filename.jpg")
```

You can use also use:

```
 import urllib.request
 urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg", "local-filename.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have imported `urllib.request` module, doesn't it seem obvious that you should call its method `urlretrieve(args)` as `urllib.request.urlretrieve(args)`.

1. When you type `import <module>`, you call its method using `<module>.method(args)` (As specified in above code).
2. Alternatively, you can import the module using `from <module> import *` and then call its method using `method(args)`. Eg -

   `from urllib.request import *`

   `urlretrieve(args)`.
3. Another way is to only import the method you need to use in your program using 
   `from <module> import method` and then call the method using `method(args)`. Eg -

`from urllib.request import urlretrieve` and then call the method using

`urlretrieve(args)`.

The `urllib.request` module for Python 3 is well documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html).