# Get Facebook profile picture using API and save it to a project folder

Tags: jquery, html, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the users facebook profile picture and save it to a folder inside the project folder. By using this I can get the facebook pic; it displays the pic. Is there any possible way to download this picture and store inside a particular folder?

```
function getPhoto()
    {
      FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {

          var str="<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src='"+response.data.url+"'/>";
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+=str;

    });
```

Comment: Can you also access the FB user server-side, as in do you have him authenticated there, you could or upload the `response.data.url` or just make a FB API call from the server

Comment: Why don't you use server side scripting language like `PHP` for this???

Comment: server side is in python. I didn't write anything there. I just tried out this http://hayageek.com/facebook-javascript-sdk/ and it's working. I only want to get the facebook profile pic not other details.

Comment: You can simply send url of profile pic using `ajax` to python and save it as you want. @MichelleDeWaasGunawardena

Comment: @Manwal I'm kind of new to this python and web development. So if I send the image URL to python can I save the image in a static folder?

Comment: @MichelleDeWaasGunawardena: check this link:
http://www.jensbits.com/2013/04/04/get-facebook-profile-picture-with-javascript-sdk/

Comment: Sure @MichelleDeWaasGunawardena if you send image URL to python you can simply same image in static folder see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286352/how-to-save-an-image-locally-using-python-whose-url-address-i-already-know

Comment: @Manwal Thank you so much I'll try it out. But it's little hard to get the URL

Comment: @MichelleDeWaasGunawardena its not hard you are already getting URL in `response.data.url`.

Comment: Yes but if you copy paste that to the browser it will give an error message https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/10447748_10201164469474360_4694721062997975871_n.jpg?oh=e11d1a96e4c9945c0116226b390760e2&amp;oe=546C237F&amp;__gda__=1417633262_5e734ee5959c13221f86c2e572cece78

Answer (score 0):

javascript can't access files in the browser, you can do it on the server with nodejs. You can only store cookies in the browser.

[Read/write to file using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You got facebook profile URL right.. Then send it to backend via Ajax. You problem will be solved.

Comment: I'm kind of new to this python and web development. So if I send the image URL to python can I save the image in a static folder?

Comment: Yes.. You can download image using the URL in your python and store it in your folder