# Unable to download image using python

Tags: python, image, download, urllib, ioerror

I am new to programing in general and was tasked with downloading an image using python, however I am having trouble getting any image.  For an example I am using:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(i.imgur.com/oFwqoz6.png, Meme.png)
```

and always receive the say error which is:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'i.imgur.com/oFwqoz6.png'
```

this baffles me due to the link working in the web browser, am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Please show us a working example that reproduces the issue, see [mcve]. Your code, as posted, won't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve("http://i.imgur.com/oFwqoz6.png", "local-filename.png")
```

This is a simple task for Python and there are many ways to solve this, after I searched for a few seconds I found many answer for this question:

[How to save an image locally using Python whose URL address I already know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286352/how-to-save-an-image-locally-using-python-whose-url-address-i-already-know)

[Downloading a picture via urllib and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python)

What I'm trying to say is that you should try to research a little bit more before formulating a question. Always post code that works, to make sure we can replicate any error you're getting.

Comment: Wow, that was simple, thank you for the help.  I'll make sure to research a bit more before posting a question again.