# Python- Scraping images using requests

Tags: python, request, python-requests

I'm unable to save/download the images at the location. I can't figure out the problem although the code seems right.

I'm using requests library for scraping the images.

```
import os
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

from lxml.html import fromstring

r = requests.get("https://www.scoopwhoop.com/subreddit-nature/#.lce3tjfci")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

title = fromstring(r.content).findtext('.//title')

#print(title)


newPath = r'C:\Users\Vicky\Desktop\ScrappedImages\ ' + title

for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    image = link.get('src')
    if 'http' in image:
        print(image)
        imageName = os.path.split(image)[1]
        print(imageName)

        r2 = requests.get(image)

        if not os.path.exists(newPath):
            os.makedirs(newPath)
            with open(imageName, "wb") as f:
                f.write(r2.content)
```

Comment: What error are you getting, if any?

Comment: you have to add and else, to that if, because if the path exist then it will do nothing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save an image locally using Python whose URL address I already know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286352/how-to-save-an-image-locally-using-python-whose-url-address-i-already-know)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `r = requests.get("https://www.scoopwhoop.com/subreddit-nature/#.lce3tjfci")` in a `try:` or `while:` statement to make sure that the website you are scraping is returning a 200 response, it could be that the website is timing out or not serving your request.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import requests
import urlparse

from lxml.html import fromstring

r = requests.get("https://www.scoopwhoop.com/subreddit-nature/#.lce3tjfci")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    image = link.get('src')
    if bool(urlparse.urlparse(image).netloc):
        print(image)
        imageName = image[image.rfind("/")+1:]
        print(imageName)

        urllib.urlretrieve(image,imageName)
```