# How do i download a image from a URL into a specific folder

Tags: python, image, url, download, urllib

I've been trying to write a function that receives a list of URLs and downloads each image from each URL to a given folder. I understand that I am supposed to be using the urlib library but I am not sure how..
the function should start like this :

```
def download_images(img_urls, dest_dir):
```

I don't even know how to start and could only find information online on how to download an image but not into a specific folder. If anyone can help me understand how to do the above, it would be wonderful.

thank you in advance:)

Comment: you are supposed to use [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library not urllib

Comment: Break up the problem: Figure out how to access a URL, then figure out how to get an image from there, then figure out how to save that image to a folder. [OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) is a good module for loading and saving images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save an image locally using Python whose URL address I already know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286352/how-to-save-an-image-locally-using-python-whose-url-address-i-already-know)

Comment: Check out this SO thread with a similar question, using urllib:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://image-url', '/dest/path/file_name.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library, for example:

```
import requests

image_url = 'https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w2000/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png'
try:
    response = requests.get(image_url)  
except:
    print('Error')    
else:
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open('stackoverflow-1.png', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it's a simple solution for your problem using `urllib.request.urlretrieve` for download the image from your url list `img_urls` and `os.path.basename` to get the file name from the url so you can save it with its original name in your `dest_dir`

```py
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import os

def download_images(img_urls, dest_dir):
    for url in img_urls:
        urlretrieve(url, dest_dir+os.path.basename(url))
```