# How do I scan for an attached image discord.py?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, discord, discord.py

I want tomake a command that basically takes an image that the user sent.
I'm using the pillow library.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def task(ctx):
    userimg = attachment.url[0].url
    print(userimg.size)
    background = Image.open("task_failed.jpg")
    print(background.size)
    size = (640,2030)
    background = background.resize(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
    background.paste(userimg, (0, 0), userimg)
    background.save('memetask',"PNG")
```

How am I supposed to complete this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save an image locally using Python whose URL address I already know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286352/how-to-save-an-image-locally-using-python-whose-url-address-i-already-know)

Comment: no, im trying to paste an image that the user sent above the image that i configured using Pillow

Comment: As you have the url of the attached image, you are able to save it with the question you sent. Note that there is also an in-built save function: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment.save I can't help you with PIL in itself.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Stack Overflow! Secondly, what version of dpy are you using? pass_context is quite old when it comes to the latest versions.