# download an image with python

Tags: python, html, web

Hi I want to download an image in this [link](https://cdn.mangaeden.com/mangasimg/20/200cce46395205ec41e1415dae82d0f625dd369e8c09b70f0b2ccf8e.jpg),
but I can't open the created image. This is the output file
[image]
How can I solve this?
This is the code:

```
from requests.models import Response
import requests

url = 'https://beta.mangaeden.com/it/it-manga/jojo-no-kimyou-na-bouken---jojorion/1/1'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
immagine = soup.find(id='mainImg')
src = str(immagine.get('src'))
link_immagine = "https:"+src
print(link_immagine)
'''download imagege'''
response = requests.get(link_immagine)
f = open("C:\\Users\\chris\\Desktop\\image.jpg", "wb")
f.write(response.content)
f.close()
print('download successfull')
```

Comment: please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8286449/11754210

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download image using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests)

Comment: This is not a problem with downloading the image but with the access of the image. There is a 403 response on making the request.

Answer (score 0):

That website seems to return `403 Forbidden` errors based on your user agent. It should work if you request the image using a browser's user agent, for example:

```
response = requests.get(link_immagine, headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0 Safari/537.36'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem while downloading this image is actually with getting the request as the response return the image link is `403` but if you set the `User-Agent` in the headers, it will do the trick and you get `200` after that you can save the image.

```py
from requests.models import Response
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://beta.mangaeden.com/it/it-manga/jojo-no-kimyou-na-bouken---jojorion/1/1'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
immagine = soup.find(id='mainImg')
src = str(immagine.get('src'))
link_image = "https:"+src
print(link_image)
'''download link_image'''
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.2 Safari/605.1.15'}
response = requests.get(link_image,headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    with open("download.jpg", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
else:
  print("NOT FOUND")
```

The image that you were saving earlier was just a response from 403 Forbidden and was not the actual image data.