# Save the API response (Json format ) as image file locally to system

Tags: python, json, api, jpeg

Below is the api response im getting  :::

```
{"contentType":"image/jpeg","createdTime":"2021-10-10T11:00:47.000Z","fileName":"Passport_Chris J Passport Color - pp.jpg","id":10144,"size":105499,"updatedTime":"2021-10-10T11:00:47.000Z","links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://dafzprod.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/CompanyRegd.ManagerDetails/43/FileAttachments/10144?download="},{"rel":"canonical","href":"https://dafzprod.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/CompanyRegd.ManagerDetails/43/FileAttachments/10144"},{"rel":"describedby","href":"https://dafzprod.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/metadata-catalog/CompanyRegd.ManagerDetails/FileAttachments","mediaType":"application/schema+json"}]}
```

i need to save this file as jpg format locally to my system?  could you please provide me a solution through python

Comment: Would be great if you provide some more information on what you have already tried and why your approach failed.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to decode the JSON-string (if not already done):

```
import json
json_decoded = json.loads(json_string)
```

Afterwards you can get the URL to retrieve and the filename from this JSON-structure

```
url = json_decoded['links'][0]['href']
local_filename = json_decoded['fileName']
```

Now you can download the file and save it (as seen here [How to save an image locally using Python whose URL address I already know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286352/how-to-save-an-image-locally-using-python-whose-url-address-i-already-know)):

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, local_filename)
```

Comment: I am getting an error at the last line  where we save locally,  it shows HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
  File "C:\Users\Alzone.DESKTOP-BINFAND\Documents\Uiauto\tesst.py", line 6, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, local_filename)

Comment: @muhamedfasil If I request the mentioned URL I get an errormessage within the server's response "Request does not contain OSvC-CREST-Application-Context header". Something is missing in the request - maybe some credentials?