# How to save an image "through" Selenium with Python and PhantomJS Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, download, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I want to download images "through" the same session that my PhantomJS instance has created. This means I can't just get the `src` attribute of the image and download it using urllib or requests or equivalent.

How do I do one of

(1) open a new tab in the PhantomJS session and browse to the image, saving the file to disk?
(2) Right Click on the image that was loaded in the original page request and save to disk?
(3) Some other method that "piggy-backs" off of the currently running PhantomJS session for downloading an image?

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813704/how-to-download-an-image-using-selenium-any-version ?

Comment: @Amey I would say not a duplicate because mine is uniquely about PhantomJS, so the related drivers may have different APIs.