# Selenium and asynchronous JavaScript calls

Tags: javascript, function, selenium, asynchronous, callback

i'm quite new to Selenium and JavaScript-callback functions and i have a big issue I can't solve myself. I need a specified variable using JavaScript. If I open the page with GoogleChrome and use the console to enter my JavaScript-Code I can get the variable using something like this:

```
1. var myId;
2. getSomeIdStuffInfo("somestuff",function(docId)(myId = docId));
3. return myId;
```

If I enter this lines step by step I easily get the correct value myId. But, of course, if i execute the three lines as fast as possible, i get null as return value because the callback function is not finished when i return myId. SOOOO.. if I use selenium like this:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
    String docInfoVal = (String) js.executeScript("" +
            "var myId; " +
            "getCurrentDocumentInfo(\"somestuff\"," +
                "function(docId) {" +
                    "myId = docId;" +
                "}" +
            ");" +
            "return myId;");
```

I only get null as result. So... somehow I have to "wait" for the callback function until i return myId. Do I have to use executeAsyncScript and how? I'm sitting on it for hours and tried different things but I just can't find the answer.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For asynchronous code you have to use `executeAsyncScript`:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
String docInfoVal = (String) js.executeAsyncScript("" +
        "var done = arguments[0]; " +
        "getCurrentDocumentInfo(\"somestuff\"," +
            "function(docId) {" +
                "done(docId);" +
            "}" +
        ");");
```

The script you call with `executeAsyncScript` will have a callback added to the list of arguments passed to it. Since you pass no arguments to your script, then `arguments[0]` contains the callback. Your code must call this callback when it is done working. The value you give to the callback is the value that `executeAsyncScript` returns.

In the code above, I've spelled out the call to `done` by putting it in an anonymous function but the code could be written more concisely as:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
String docInfoVal = (String) js.executeAsyncScript("" +
        "var done = arguments[0]; " +
        "getCurrentDocumentInfo(\"somestuff\", done);");
```

Or even:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
String docInfoVal = (String) js.executeAsyncScript(
        "getCurrentDocumentInfo('somestuff', arguments[0]);");
```

Comment: Out of all the example this seems easy enough to understand

Comment: Thanks for the easy explanation, it works and more important, I think I understood how :)

Answer (score 2):

Though this is almost same as what @Louis said.You have to set the [`setScriptTimeout`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeAsyncScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) beforehand for the script to pass.

> The default timeout for a script to be executed is 0ms. In most cases,
>   including the examples below, one must set the script timeout
>   WebDriver.Timeouts.setScriptTimeout(long,
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) beforehand to a value sufficiently
>   large enough.

Below is an example for which I'm waiting for 10 seconds to return a string

```
  driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//important

    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String val = (String) executor.executeAsyncScript(""
            + "var done=arguments[0]; "
            + "setTimeout(function() {"
            + "   done('tada');"
            + "  }, 10000);");

    System.out.println(val);
```

Comment: You saved me hours of mindless debugging! Thank you!