# Download images using selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I want to download and save images using selenium in python2.7

I've tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url= "https://in.images.search.yahoo.com/images/view;_ylt=A2oKiHPRis1VplIALaEO9olQ;_ylu=X3oDMTIyN2I2OHZkBHNlYwNzcgRzbGsDaW1nBG9pZANjN2U1ZjU4NjAwMDQ1MDA0OGExZGMxY2Y0MzMyMDk0MwRncG9zAzEEaXQDYmluZw--?.origin=&back=https%3A%2F%2Fin.images.search.yahoo.com%2Fyhs%2Fsearch%3Fp%3D%2522Eiffel%2BGreens%2522%2BBalewadi%2509Pune%26n%3D60%26ei%3DUTF-8%26y%3DSearch%26type%3Dff.40.w81.hp.04-01.in.avg._.0715av%26fr%3Dyhs-avg-fh_lsonsw%26fr2%3Dsb-top-in.images.search.yahoo.com%26hsimp%3Dyhs-fh_lsonsw%26hspart%3Davg%26tab%3Dorganic%26ri%3D1&w=556&h=309&imgurl=www.propertyonepune.com%2Fimg%2Fgallery%2F0becda3e53f8db646a699e54b1333a4c.jpg&rurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.propertyonepune.com%2Fproperties%2F46%2FBalewadi&size=49.8KB&name=...+bungalows+by+Eiffel+Developers+%26+Realtors+Ltd.+at+%3Cb%3EBalewadi%3C%2Fb%3E%2C+%3Cb%3EPune%3C%2Fb%3E&p=%22Eiffel+Greens%22+Balewadi%09Pune&oid=c7e5f586000450048a1dc1cf43320943&fr2=sb-top-in.images.search.yahoo.com&fr=yhs-avg-fh_lsonsw&tt=...+bungalows+by+Eiffel+Developers+%26+Realtors+Ltd.+at+%3Cb%3EBalewadi%3C%2Fb%3E%2C+%3Cb%3EPune%3C%2Fb%3E&b=0&ni=21&no=1&ts=&tab=organic&sigr=11lu74lc1&sigb=17t67hvmu&sigi=1284god0v&sigt=12i2gtekb&sign=12i2gtekb&.crumb=wZ3uTmSmDfL&fr=yhs-avg-fh_lsonsw&fr2=sb-top-in.images.search.yahoo.com&hsimp=yhs-fh_lsonsw&hspart=avg&type=ff.40.w81.hp.04-01.in.avg._.0715av"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

path = '//div[@class="iholder"]//img[@src]'
for k in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(path):
    items = []
    src = (k.get_attribute('src')).encode('utf8')
    items.append(src)
    print items
    for lm in items:
        driver.get(lm)
        driver.sendKeys(Keys.Control + "s")
        driver.send_keys(Keys.Enter)
```

It's giving me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Heypillow/Desktop/download.py", line 17, in <module>
driver.sendKeys(Keys.Control + "s")
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'sendKeys'
```

I've tried with:

```
driver.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "s")
```

Same error is showing
**What should I do to save the images?** Thanks in advance

Comment: I've edited my post. please have a look

Comment: it definitely can't be the SAME error if you change to the correct method send_keys instead of Java-Style sendKeys -> so post the error message you get if you only use send_keys

Comment: The error:  

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Heypillow/Desktop/download.py", line 17, in <module>
    driver.send_keys(Keys.Control + "s")
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'`

I didn't find it different,what am I doing wrong? @drkthng

Comment: I've tried with `driver.send_keys(u'\ue009' + 's')` too.. same error

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54986819/7484554

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, op's first attempt is more correct than the selected answer.  If you're not sending keys to an element for typing then you're sending them to the browser for shortcuts, etc.

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.Control).send_keys("s").key_up(Keys.Control)‌​‌​.perform()
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to save the html for each picture, so you could use actions to get the context-menu of firefox -> "p" is shortcut for save page:

```
for lm in items:
        driver.get(lm)
        body = driver.find_element(By.tagName("body"));
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(body).context_click(htmlElement).send_keys("p").send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform();
```

*I'm usually using Java, so there might be some typos in this python code of mine ;-)*

Comment: No actually I want to save the images as image_name.jpg files. But I'm stuck. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because `.send_keys` does not hang off of `webdriver`, it hangs off of `webelement`. You need to get a `webelement` first before trying to use `.send_keys`. For example,

```
for lm in items:
    lm.sendKeys(Keys.Control + "s")
```

This isn't going to answer your main question but it does explain why you are getting the error message.

To answer your main question, google it and you will find many responses such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361742/download-image-with-selenium-python) that already has answers.

Comment: thank you it solved my problem.. I was stuck between the concept of Webdriver and Webelement thing I believe.

Comment: this answer is not best practice (see mine below), and it could lead to race conditions with the timing of ctrl+s

Comment: The code example is not an answer, it's a code sample to demonstrate the cause of the error... which I thought was clearly stated. It should NOT be used as is because it would spam CTRL+S to all elements in `items` in a matter of a few ms.

Comment: No worries... my post was really for people coming across this from googling (there are a lot of screwy things with op's method of attack).  I've just seen too many people using send_keys for keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

The Accepted Answer has had one change since 2015.

Instead of

```py
Keys.Control
```

It has now changed to

```py
Keys.CONTROL
```

and the snippet changes to

```py
ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("s").key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```