# how to extract image with java script link?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I would like to extract the images from webpage using selenium. the code which I am trying is

```
import os
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Ie()
url_database =  "https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=773013618"
driver.get(url_database)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('menu'))
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='menu' and contains(@onclick,'toggleswitch(this)') and contains(.,'Front') and contains(@href,'javascript')]")[0]
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('menu'))

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
for link in soup.findAll('href'):
    print(link)
```

it has some images with java script link. how to extract all the images in that.

Comment: *A JavaScript Link* - not sure what you mean here but you might be confusing something.

Answer (score 0):

Your image on page is present in `src` tag not in `href` tag

Download file :-

1. Get the SRC attribute of the image.
2. Use ImageIO.read to read the image onto a BufferedImage
3. Save the BufferedImage using ImageIO.write function

source :-

[How to download an image using Selenium (any version)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813704/how-to-download-an-image-using-selenium-any-version)

refer :-

[image]

Comment: @Jack   what I mean with java script link is there is no direct image location for image it is like "<td><a href="javascript:parent.ShowImage(&#34;247246802&#34;, &#34;0&#34;, &#34;Vehicle 2 - Front&#34;, &#34;FRONT&#34;,&#34;jpg&#34;)"><img width="100px" height="78px" alt="FRONT" src="GetBinary.aspx?Image&amp;ImageID=247246802&amp;CaseID=773013618&amp;Version=0"></a><div style="text-align:center;height:50px">FRONT</div>
               </td>
" referenced with java script

Comment: even src also not giving anything with find all in Beautifulsoup.

Comment: why using BeautifulSoup for it anty special region

Comment: I am using beautifulsoup in other data extraction.so I feel if we could solve the issue with beautifulsoup. other than there is no specific reason.

Comment: there what you need to do is use code somethig like :- persons = []
for person in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@src]'):'

Comment: I have use elements not element .. there is a difference of s

Comment: you need to iterate it and you can print all  value

Comment: refer here to see an example of java:- https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8029/how-to-iterate-a-list-of-webelements-and-print-the-values-one-by-one-to-perform

Comment: I got the src info as <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="5444610e-66e1-41bf-b291-8feba24f5d7c", element="9e1bf532-c788-4357-aea8-525631f90b21")>  .... how to save that image locally. means download the image to my system?

Comment: udpated my answer