# Python requests save randomly generated image

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am attempting to use python requests in order to save an image from a webpage. However, the image is randomly generated via php, as shown by the code below, and is different each time. 
The image is used for a captcha, and changes between each request.

`<img src="image.php">`

How would I go about properly saving this image?

Comment: Have you tried to use Fiddler to see request and responce?

Comment: @CrazyElf I haven’t used fiddler, but I did use postman.  all it showed was a get request to the initial webpage, but not to the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use selenium. If you are trying to write something that can bypass captcha.

[How to save an image locally using Python whose URL address I already know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286352/how-to-save-an-image-locally-using-python-whose-url-address-i-already-know)

[How to download an image using Selenium (any version)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813704/how-to-download-an-image-using-selenium-any-version)